# Showing email null even if it is present in database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have tried to fetch the google_id by using a select query in codeigniter, but it shows the email is null even if the email is present in the database.

```
    public function loginUser( $data, $api = false) {

              $this->db->select('*');
              $this->db->from('tbl_users'); 

            /*   if(!empty($data['email']) && $api){*/

              $this->db->where('email',$data['email']); //checking user email from dbase//

               /*}
    */     if(!empty($data['fb_id']) && $api){
              $this->db->where('fb_id', $data['fb_id']);
              }
              else 
                if(!empty($data['google_id']) && $api){
                $this->db->where('google_id', $data['google_id']);
              }



              $this->db-> limit(1);
              $query = $this->db->get();
              $result = $query->row_array();
```

--

```
SELECT *
FROM (`tbl_users`)
WHERE `email` IS NULL
AND `google_id` =  '5726357629529852956'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You are using if-else statement. when IF condition is true it will not towards else statement.

Comment: if you want both fb_id and google_id then use two if statements separately

Answer (score 0):

$data['email'] might be geting a null value.check $data['email']  output.Check the controller section.